# Google map is not Rendering into div?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
  /*style for map*/   
<style>
            /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
               * element that contains the map. */
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
            /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>

/* map div*/ 
    <div class="col-md-12">

            <div id="map">

            </div>
        </div>

    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 7.8731, lng: 80.7718 },
                zoom: 8
            });
        }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAumFScM9gO2DBha7pCNH1ua3tvEWVQMsM&sensor=TRUE" async defer></script>
```

Above code is for my simple google map. But the map is not showing in view. but the map is rendered to the div after viewing it using inspect element.

Please advice me to do solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should call your initMap function from script

Answer (score 1):

**like this**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAumFScM9gO2DBha7pCNH1ua3tvEWVQMsM&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: Why will that work? What did you change? What did OP do wrong?

Comment: initmap basically sets map into div and also tells where to set bounds by taking center which has been passed

Comment: Please add this to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

'callback=initMap' was missing from the line because it will call the function specified using the callback parameter

Edit your code like

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAumFScM9gO2DBha7pCNH1ua3tvEWVQMsM&sensor=TRUE" async defer></script>
```

to

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAumFScM9gO2DBha7pCNH1ua3tvEWVQMsM&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After it's going to work.

To get a better idea follow this link [click here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Comment: Why will it work? What did you change? What did OP do wrong?

Comment: 'callback=initMap' was missing from the line because it will call the function specified using the callback parameter

Comment: Please add this to your answer.

Comment: I added it, Thank you.